# items not removed correctly from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I heard that if we want to remove any item from our RecyclerView we can use this method for example:

```
private void removeItem(int position){
        recordingArrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemChanged(position, recordingArrayList.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But seems I missed something, here is my `RecordingListActivity .java`:

```
public class RecordingListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerViewRecordings;
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
private BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;
private ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList;
private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
private RecordingAdapter recordingAdapter;
private TextView textViewNoRecordings;
private TimeAgo timeAgo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording_list);

    timeAgo = new TimeAgo();
    initViews();
    fetchRecordings();
}

private void initViews() {
    recordingArrayList = new ArrayList<Recording>();

    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    recyclerViewRecordings = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRecordings);
    recyclerViewRecordings.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerViewRecordings.setHasFixedSize(true);
    new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewRecordings);

    textViewNoRecordings = findViewById(R.id.textViewNoRecordings);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.fab){
                openHome();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void openHome(){
    Intent home = new Intent(RecordingListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(home);
}

private void fetchRecordings() {

    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AbdulhaleemRecorderApp/Audios";
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
            String fileName = files[i].getName();
            String recordingUri = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AbdulhaleemRecorderApp/Audios/" + fileName;
            Double size = (double) files[i].length() / 1024;
            String time = timeAgo.getTimeAgo(files[i].lastModified());
            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

            Recording recording = new Recording(recordingUri, fileName, date, size, time,false);
            recordingArrayList.add(recording);
        }

        textViewNoRecordings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerViewRecordings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setAdaptertoRecyclerView();

    } else {
        textViewNoRecordings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerViewRecordings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}


private void setAdaptertoRecyclerView() {
    recordingAdapter = new RecordingAdapter(this, recordingArrayList);
    recyclerViewRecordings.setAdapter(recordingAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
    }

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
        removeItem(position);

    }
};

private void removeItem(int position){
    recordingArrayList.remove(position);
    recordingAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    recordingAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position, recordingArrayList.size());
    recordingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

here is my `RecordingAdapter.java`

```
public class RecordingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList;
private Context context;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private boolean isPlaying = false;
private int last_index = -1;

public RecordingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.recordingArrayList = recordingArrayList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recording_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    setUpData(holder, position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recordingArrayList.size();
}

private void setUpData(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Recording recording = recordingArrayList.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(recording.getFileName());
    holder.textViewDate.setText(recording.getDate());
    holder.textViewSize.setText(String.format("%.2f", (double) (recording.getSize())) + " KB");
    holder.textViewTime.setText(recording.getTime());

    if (recording.isPlaying()) {
        holder.imageViewPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) holder.itemView);
        holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.seekUpdation(holder);
    } else {
        holder.imageViewPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) holder.itemView);
        holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.manageSeekBar(holder);

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    SeekBar seekBar;
    ImageView imageViewPlay;
    ImageView imageViewShare;
    ImageView imageViewEdit;
    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewDate;
    TextView textViewSize;
    TextView textViewTime;
    TextView textViewPhoneNumber;
    private String recordingUri;
    private int lastProgress = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        final Context vhContext = itemView.getContext();

        seekBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        imageViewPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlay);
        imageViewShare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShare);
        imageViewEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEdit);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecordingname);
        textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        textViewSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSize);
        textViewTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        textViewPhoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhoneNumber);

        imageViewShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Recording recording = recordingArrayList.get(position);
                recordingUri = recording.getUri();

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/mp3");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, recordingUri);
                vhContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share " + recording.getFileName() + " using:"));
            }
        });

        imageViewPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Recording recording = recordingArrayList.get(position);

                recordingUri = recording.getUri();

                if (isPlaying) {
                    stopPlaying();
                    if (position == last_index) {
                        recording.setPlaying(false);
                        stopPlaying();
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                    } else {
                        markAllPaused();
                        recording.setPlaying(true);
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                        startPlaying(recording, position);
                        last_index = position;
                    }

                } else {
                    startPlaying(recording, position);
                    recording.setPlaying(true);
                    seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
                    Log.d("isPlayin", "False");
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                    last_index = position;
                }

            }

        });
    }

    public void manageSeekBar(ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (mPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                    mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void markAllPaused() {
        for (int i = 0; i < recordingArrayList.size(); i++) {
            recordingArrayList.get(i).setPlaying(false);
            recordingArrayList.set(i, recordingArrayList.get(i));
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation(holder);
        }
    };

    private void seekUpdation(ViewHolder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            int mCurrentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            holder.seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
            holder.seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
            lastProgress = mCurrentPosition;
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        try {
            mPlayer.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPlayer = null;
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    private void startPlaying(final Recording audio, final int position) {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(recordingUri);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "prepare() failed");
        }
        //showing the pause button
        seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
        isPlaying = true;

        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                audio.setPlaying(false);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

when I swap the item it seems it deleted, but when I  open another activity and come back again the deleted item comes back again like it is never deleted, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corresponding to your code it's expected behaviour. So, your code fetches files data from device file system in `onCreate()` method of your activity and creates **a list of representation of the files**.
When `recordingArrayList.remove(position);` is invoked, it removes item from the **representation list**, but **not file from file system**.
When you call another activity and goes back, activity with the list is created again and `onCreate()` is called again and your code fetches again all the files from device file system and shows it in a list.
Possible solution can be: remove file from file system, if you have read-write access to this folder or save a list in your app. For example, in Room database and add to your file representation field `isDeleted` and use data from database to show in a list.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain, I did what you said, and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the changes to the file and when you reload the activity, the array is fetched again from the file which hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your removeItem function should be in adapter class or after removing you should pass changed list to adapter and after that notify changes. In your case you actually not removing item from adapter (because list in activity and list in adapter are different (different instances)).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to delete the file name from where you are reading the file too, cause when you remove an item from the list it isn't removed from the file. So when removing remove its element from the list too.
Try to keep your logic for adapter change in your adapter only.

I'll suggest you make a method name `setData(ArrayList<Recording> recordingsList)` in your recycler view.

> In RecordingAdapter

```
public class RecordingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordingAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public RecordingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recordingArrayList = recordingArrayList;
    }
// added
    public setData(ArrayList<Recording> recordingsList) {
        this.recordingArrayList = recordingsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And when you swipe to delete call the RecordingAdapter `setData(RecordingLists)` method

> RecordingListActivity

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
        recordingArrayList.remove(position);
        recordingAdapter.setData(recordingArrayList); // changed
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First **remove** item from the list then **refresh** your adapter by `notifyItemRangeChanged` with new size of the list and most important you need to **update** the data which you are fetching for `recycler-view`.

```
recordingArrayList.remove(position);       
notifyItemRangeChanged(position,recordingArrayList.size());
```